# What is the best way to deploy a Jar file?

Tags: github, deployment, travis-ci

### Background

I'm working on a project where we host a Java software and an R companion package on [Github](https://github.com/leifeld/dna). The R package can be easily installed directly from source using `devtools::install_github()` but the Jar file has to be built first.

As the R package depends on functions in the Jar file, this creates a problem since Jar and R package are often out of sync and users can't utilize newer functions until we make a new release. Since the changes in the Jar are often tiny it doesn't always make sense to create a new release though.

### Ideal solution (?)

There are two approaches which I could think of but I'm not quite sure which makes more sense and would have to spend some more time figuring each one out:

1. Write a function in R which downloads the source from GitHub and builds the Jar via something like `system("jar cfe myJar.jar myClass myClass.class"`. Ideally, there is a package for this but I couldn't find one. I would also first have to figure out how to download the source files though.
2. Implement an automatic deploy that uploads the Jar to the same release after every commit. I saw that Travis CI can build the Jar file but it creates a new release for every commit or only from tagged commits, which is not ideal. It would be better if we could have one release which is overwritten with the most current Jar file on every commit.

Does anybody have experience with this/can point me to a repository where something like this is implemented/can show me a better solution?

Comment: If the difference between one jar and the next is whether integration with another component works or fails, then why on Earth would the fact that the code change is "small" have anything to do with whether a new release makes sense?  You're not going to run out of numbers

Comment: Thanks, that's a fair point. Our plan was to only publish releases when there is something genuinely new. But I think you are right and we should just make releases more frequently.